# Writing to buffer before writing to file to avoid being locked out

Tags: c#, io, buffer

I am currently working on a c# project where I need to write content to a file. While the file is being written a separate thread accesses the file to get the file size so sometimes as I am writing to the file it gets locked out as the file size check has the file locked.

What I was thinking of doing is creating some sort of buffer but whenever I google it, it comes back about network streams which isn't suitable as its all local. What the plan was instead of the thread writing directly to the file, it writes to some sort of buffer, and a separate thread checks if the file is writable and then reads the buffer and writes the contents to the file.

The other problem is I need to add a parameter so that when it does write to the file it writes to the correct file as my program is receiving input from multiple places so I need to keep this value somewhere in the buffer but from what I have seen of streams you can only write strings.

So the basic question is how can I write to a buffer and then read from a buffer so that it can be written to a file and keep a parameter within the buffer so that when it writes to the file it know which file to write to.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Perhaps instead of a buffer, you need [locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

Comment: And instead of having one buffer, have one buffer per output file.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a class that has buffer space and the file spec.  Create one for each write and queue it to the BackgroundWorker write thread. The thread dequeues the buffer instance and writes the file with suitable sleep() loop etry to ensure that any temporary file lock is worked around.

You could use a BlockingCollection for the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a file's length should not lock the file. How are you doing that operation?

If you use a buffer your length check operation won't give you the correct value any more.